# odroidxu4 changing default uart2 to uart0

Tags: linux, uart

previously thank you for watching this post.

I have tried to run linux on odroidxu4 and of course the logs are written through uart2 (this uart seems default in odroidxu4)

But what I'm trying to do is changing the linux to write the logs with uart0 not the uart2.

I tried to change the default uart port from 2 to 0 by modifying the code in common/serial.c in u-boot

and also tried to change the menuconfig in linux like below :

1. kernel hacking => Kernel low-level debugging functions
2. choose in "Kernel low-level debugging port" to "Use S3C UART 0 for low-level debug"

But it didn't work.

please let me know if there's another way to change the dafault uart from 2 to 0 that i missed

thank you.

Comment: What distribution? What about the kernel command line? Is U-Boot the bootloader?

Comment: Linux : I'm not sure about distribution but i cloned from this URL (https://github.com/hardkernel/linux.git)

the commandline is "root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootwait ro fsck.repair=yes console=ttySAC2,115200n8 mem=512mb"

and the U-boot is also from hardkernel distribution and it is one of bootloaders that commonly used in embedded system

Comment: Well, changing the `console=` you could change where the Linux outputs go but the U-Boot outputs would still remain.

Comment: As you mentioned boot command line, I also changed the command ttySAC2 to ttySAC0 it worked well. thank you.
I want to vote your answer if you post your answer not comment if  you want

Comment: Good idea, this might help someone else as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concerning the output from Linux (and not your bootloader, i.e. U-Boot or possible something before that), you would simply change the `console=` command line parameter, see http://elinux.org/Serial_console and https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.txt.

Comment: "https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kernel-parameters.txt" this link is not available...

Comment: @JuengwooYu Thank you, I fixed it. Apparently, the link has changed quite recently.